# Subtracting two pandas timezone aware timestamps gives TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two timezone aware pandas datetime timestamps. When I subtract them I get the error:

```
TypeError: Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones
```

The first is from a conversion to pandas datetime:

```
start_time = pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime(2019, 6, 28, 0, 52, 57, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc))
```

The second is from a DataFrame index which looks like this:

```
>> phase_df.index[0]
Timestamp('2019-06-28 00:52:30.000130+0000', tz='UTC')
```

To confirm they are both of the same type:

```
>> type(phase_df.index[0]), type(start_time)
(pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp,
 pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the only solution I could find was to remove all timezone information prior to subtraction.

```
start_time = pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime(2019, 6, 28, 0, 52, 57, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc)).tz_localize(None)

other_time = phase_df.index.tz_localize(None)

start_time - other_time
```

Gives no error. But it should really be able to work with timezones. Must be a bug.

Comment: I hit the same issue today and found this post.  I agree,  sounds like a bug.  I would also say that an added feature would be that datetime subtraction of time zone aware timestamps should just work too.  Internally,  convert them to utc,  then subtract.